# I have a compass but no watch, how can I tell when it will get dark?

Tags: gear, navigation, compasses

I was reading all of the answers to [Are there any situations while backpacking that would require a watch?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/15370) and surprised at the number of answers that said you need a watch so you would know how long until dark.  People have been walking around the world for a very long time, portable time pieces have only been readily available for about hundred years. They do have a [longer history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_watches) but spent much of that time as very high end luxury items.

The compass has a much [longer history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_compass), it is simpler instrument, with a much lower cost to acquire and maintain.

A watch alone, will not tell you when it going to get dark, nor when the tides will be low, but combined with other information it can help you determine when the forecast event will occur.

If I have a compass, how can I use it to estimate how long until sun set?

Comment: The compass and your shadow can tell you when it is noon.  Then if you know the date, you can estimate your latitude from the length of your shadow.  Time from noon to sunset is a function of date and latitude.

Comment: @WGroleau a few more details and that could be an answer.... :)

Comment: When I geta better internet connection, perhaps.  :-)

Comment: My understanding of this is that while it can be done, it requires more tables and math than I would like to do in the outdoors.

Comment: *surprised at the number of answers that said you need a watch so you would know how long until dark* I don't think anyone said that. A bunch of people, including me, pointed out that a watch is useful for that purpose, but none of us claimed it was the only way to do it.

Comment: @BenCrowell one example [To know when it's going to get dark!](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/15370/are-there-any-situations-while-backpacking-that-would-require-a-watch/15373#15373)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't need a compass, nor any mechanical tool at all.  You just need your fingers.  I've linked an article with illustrations at the end, but here is the basic idea:

1. Stand facing the sun, extend your arms out fully, and bend your hands inward.
2. Rotate your fingers to be parallel to the horizon, and move your hand(s) to position them between the horizon and the sun.
3. Count how many fingers are between the horizon and the bottom of the sun.
4. Each finger means 10 to 15 minutes (different sources give different estimates, my own experience doing this is closer to 10.)

As pointed out in comments, this technique only gives an approximation.  Its usefulness may depend on terrain and even your latitude.

Here's the article: [How to Find Out How Much Time Is Left Before Sunset](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-Out-How-Much-Time-Is-Left-Before-Sunset).

Comment: This method will beat a watch anytime in mountain or  canyon areas where sun's path is intercepted by the terrain.

Comment: This answer is wrong, as is the linked wikihow page. As an extreme example, if you're above the arctic circle, then it could be 6 months until sunset. This kind of thing depends on both the latitude and time of year.

Comment: @BenCrowell It's an excellent approximation technique. As most people in the outdoors don't need to know the exact time, this method will work fine for most of them.

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh: No, it's not an excellent approximation technique if it tells you the sun will set in 1 hour and actually it will set in 6 months.

Comment: If you are one of the **0.053 percent** of the human population that lives above the arctic circle then yes it might throw you off. However, for the vast **majority** of the population its is a good **approximation** to at least a quarter hour or so.

Comment: @BenCrowell - I've added a sentence to the answer to clarify, thanks.

Comment: I was going to post this as an answer, I've been using this method for years.

Comment: @BenCrowell - To make this method work you only need to adjust the number of minutes for finger. However, for most of relevant practical applications, you will need larger corrections for finger width and arm length than for geographical position.